# How to loop select statement based on the previous select statement?

Tags: sql, loops

[image]
I need all the data to be in one straight line.

I need to create a report and for that i need to summarize all.
So i did this select statement first.
**Query1**

```
Select  t1.scn,t1.vsl_name,  t1.act_arr_dt_tm, t1.act_dept_dt_tm, t1.del_remarks
from vesvoy t1
```

So based on the select statement above i need to get all the **t1.scn** to loop the below sql

**Query2**

```
Select  t1.scn,t2.void_flg,
MAX(case when t2.inv_num like 'VI%' then t2.inv_num end) as Vessel,
MAX(case when t2.inv_num like 'VI%' then t2.inv_amt end) as Vessel_amt
from pbosinvoiceitem t1
inner join pbosinvoice t2 ON t2.id = t1.master_id
inner join pbosinvtype t4 ON t4.code = t2.inv_type
group by t1.scn,t2.void_flg
```

so that i can get the result like in the report. I have try to create temp table but the data that i get is all duplicate.

I try combining both queries but the result shows duplicate result

Comment: Your report screen capture is showing no data.

Comment: This would be easier if you posted sample data and expected results.  No need to use `distinct` with `group by`.  If you combine the queries, what data is "duplicated"?  Assuming each field is in the `group by` clause, it will retrun `distinct` data for that row.  You need to do a better job defining your question...

Answer (score 1):

I'm sitting here thinking:  "What does the first query have to do with the second?"  Both are on the same table, `vesvoy`, so what could the question be.  The second is processing the same rows as the first.

I suspect the issue is that the `join`s are losing rows.  So, I suspect that the answer is use `left join`, rather than `inner join`.  Along the way, get rid of the `select distinct`.  This is generally a bad idea.  In combination with a `group by` on the same non-aggregated columns, it just shows a lack of awareness of SQL.

So, does this address your concern?

```
SELECT t1.scn,
       MAX(case when t3.inv_num like 'VI%' then t3.inv_num end) as Vessel,
       MAX(case when t3.inv_num like 'VI%' then t3.inv_amt end) as Vessel_amt
FROM vesvoy t1 LEFT JOIN
     pbosinvoiceitem t2
     ON t2.scn = t1.scn LEFT JOIN
     pbosinvoice t3
     ON t3.id = t2.master_id
GROUP BY t1.scn;
```

This will return `NULL` for the non-matching rows.